# compare between two image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram

I am working on a project and retrieval of images you compare the two images, but I do not know how the two images are similar Al histogram has been used to compare the images and I tried in this code
I hope to help me and I will be grateful to you

```
A=imread('D:\Image Retrieval\21.bmp');
B=imread('D:\Image Retrieval\22.bmp');
A1=rgb2hsv(A);
B1=rgb2hsv(B);

[M,N,ttt] = size(A);
range = 0.0:0.1:1.0;
Hist = zeros(length(range),length(range),length(range));
for i=1:M
    for j=1:N
        N1 = histc(A1(i,j,1), range);
        N2 = histc(A1(i,j,2), range);
        N3 = histc(A1(i,j,3), range);                

       nn1 = histc(B1(i,j,1), range);
       nn2 = histc(B1(i,j,2), range);
       nn3 = histc(B1(i,j,3), range); 


    end
end
Hist = Hist / (M*N);
subplot(2,2,1);imshow(A);
subplot(2,2,2);imshow(A1);
subplot(2,2,3);imshow(B);
subplot(2,2,4);imshow(B1);
```

Comment: Well, using a histogram only tells you the color contents of the image. If this is enough for comparison, then you could use the imhist method to calculate the histrogram for you.   http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html

Comment: Would the correlation coefficient suffice?

Comment: Is it possible to be used for comparison imhist .. Do I have to get the correct results, and I deal with color images

Comment: Professorial on the project asked me two methods for comparison correlation  and  heistogram